# GooglePlus Sign In issue

Tags: ios8, xcode6, interface-builder, google-plus-signin

After a lot of search I have to go for my own question, I am using `google plus login` in my `iOS` App but failing.

When I assigned the class `GPPSignInButton` to the button which I want to make the G+ sign in button, after running the app it shows a message named `Unknown class “GPPSignInButton” in Interface Builder file.`

I did a lot of research on the internet and found some solutions but none of them worked, as I added the linker flag, my application fails to build and the error is

> `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)`

I tried using `-all_load -ObjC` as well as `-ObjC` and `-ObjC -lc++` but all of them fail with the same code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that it was giving the issue of duplicate files, that were present in `Bolts.framework` and `FacebookSDK.framework` both. After that I found out that `FacebookSDK.framework` was not needed there and so I removed it and the app started working perfectly.